# Algorithm performance on applying operations during loop versus when loop finishes?

Tags: php, algorithm, performance, optimization

The question is rather confusing, so let me elaborate, look at the two snippets of pseudo-code below:

**Looping-and-applying:**

```
$numbers = [1, 1, 1]
$final   = 0;
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
  $final = $final + ($number * 0.95);
}
```

**Looping-then-applying:**

```
$numbers = [1, 1, 1]
$final   = 0;
foreach ($numbers as $number) {
  $final = $final + $number;
}
$final = ($final * 0.95);
```

Where the first snippet is adding **95% of each number** to the **final** number, and the second snippet is adding **100% of each number**, then once done, taking **95%**.

Each result will conclude the same result: **2.85**. But I'm curious if performance varies at a macro level.

Comment: Don't worry about this kind of performance, worry about making your code easier to read... `$final + ( array_sum($numbers) * 0.95 )`

Comment: @Scuzzy in most circumstances I'd use `array_sum` functions and `map` functions, I was just trying to deconstruct my question to show what logic I was talking about. **I'm generally curious about ways performance works**, but I'm not a performance buff ahha.

Comment: After writing and testing a very short benchmark script for this, it appears the obvious answer is correct: the second method, summing up then scaling (12.9ms), is ~2ms faster in 1 million iterations than the first variant (15ms). In any case, if you're going to iterate over stupendously sized data sets where this kind of performance matters, PHP is likely the wrong tool for the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wrote a simple test block and added the two variations you have above plus a variation of looping-then-applying using `array_sum`. Each function is run 10,000,000 times (average of 10 iterations of 1,000,000 iterations of each).

```
$tests = [
    function ($numbers) {
        $final   = 0;
        foreach ($numbers as $number) {
            $final = $final + ($number * 0.95);
        }
        return $final;
    },
    function ($numbers) {
        $final   = 0;
        foreach ($numbers as $number) {
            $final = $final + $number;
        }
        return ($final = ($final * 0.95));
    },
    function ($numbers) {
        return array_sum($numbers) * 0.95;
    }
];

$numbers = [1, 1, 1];

$loop = range(1, 1000000);
$reps = range(1,10);

$testRes = [];

foreach($tests as $idx => $test) {

    foreach($reps as $rep) {
        $s = microtime(true);

        foreach($loop as $l) {
            $test($numbers);
        }

        $e = microtime(true);
        if( !isset($testRes[$idx]) ) {
            $testRes[$idx] = [];
        }
        $testRes[$idx][] = $e - $s;
    }

}

foreach($testRes as $idx => $res) {
    $avg = array_sum($res) / count($res);
    print_r("Test {$idx} took an average " . (string) $avg . ' seconds.<br />');
}
```

Results?

```
// Test 0 took an average 0.1228661775589 seconds.
// Test 1 took an average 0.11786506175995 seconds.
// Test 2 took an average 0.10405595302582 seconds.
```

Test 0 is the looping-and-applying function and takes the longest.
Test 1 is the looping-then-applying function which was 5 thousandths of a second faster.
Test 2 is the looping-then-applying function but using `array_sum` instead of scripted addition operations and take a bit more than 1 hundredth of a second faster than Test 1.

Why? The answer of why looping-then-applying is faster than looping-and-applying is simple math: you are applying 2 math operations per array entry (3 entries in the array * 2 operations = 6 operations per loop) in the looping-and-applying example. Compare that to the 1 math operation per array entry in the looping-then-applying function (3 entries in the array * 1 operation = 3 operations per loop).

Wait, 1/2 the operations... why isn't the speed twice as fast?

PHP has plenty of overhead (things like actually executing partially compiled scripts that are not always perfectly optimized, writing over existing variables has overhead, etc.) which is why you don't see twice the speed for half the operations.

So why is the `array_sum` example fastest? Isn't it the same as the looping-then-applying function? In principle, yes. However, it has one major advantage - the part that loops over and adds the values from the array is compiled code from the PHP's source (written in the C language) so that part of it does not suffer from having to execute partially compiled the code. Because of this, most (but not all) built-in PHP functions will be faster than using your own scripted function that does the same thing. It all depends on the situation and requirements.

Comment: This was really intuitive, thanks so much for this. I'm going to play with it a bit but the whole compiled C code really made sense. Regards! :D